# How can i extract only links of images using htmlagilitpack?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm using this code:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            backgroundWorker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
            if (backgroundWorker != null)
            {

                while (!backgroundWorker.CancellationPending)
                {
                        if (backgroundWorker.CancellationPending)
                        {
                            e.Cancel = true;
                            break;
                        }
                        if (newHtmls.Count == 1)
                            break;

                        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb hw = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();
                        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = hw.Load("https://www.test.com");
                        htmls = new List<string>();
                        foreach (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
                        {
                            string hrefValue = link.GetAttributeValue("href", string.Empty);
                                if (!newHtmls.Contains(hrefValue))
                                    newHtmls.Add(hrefValue);
                        }

                    while (true)
                    {
                        if (backgroundWorker.CancellationPending)
                        {
                            e.Cancel = true;
                            break;
                        }
                        htmlloaded = true;
                        NavigateToLinks();
                        break;
                    }
                }                
            }            
        }
```

Now it will add any link.
I tried to change the IF to:

```
if (!newHtmls.Contains(hrefValue) && hrefValue.Contains("img"))
```

But this will give me only two links.
Maybe the problem is some of the links most of them are long over more then two lines ?

But in general what i want to get is only images links.
Could be links that contain img or image or jpg.....could be more cases.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: Fixed conversion issue**

How about something like this

```
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb hw = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = hw.Load("https://www.test.com");

        var hrefs = (from image in doc.DocumentNode.Descendants()
                        where image.Name == "img" &&
                            image.ParentNode.Name == "a"
                        select image.ParentNode).ToList();

        foreach (var href in hrefs)
        {
            newHtmls.Add(href.GetAttributeValue("href", ""));
        }
```

Comment: I'm getting error on .ToList() since i'm using my already variable newHtmls and it's List<string>

Comment: Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'

Comment: Use the result produced by the code from @CLaff as the "list of nodes" that you iterate in your `foreach`.  Something like: `foreach (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode link in newHtmls)` ...This should resolve the `cannot implicitly convert type` problem.